# how many bits correspond to N hexadecimal digits?

Tags: binary, hex, data-conversion, converters, bin

The answer is not so simple. I know that generally 1 hex digit is mapped on 4 bits, but this is not even true. What appen if the MSB (the most left) is a 0?
Online I noticed that this string is converted sometimes to 476 digits, sometimes to 478 digits and sometimes to 480 digits? How do you convert it? And why? It's 120 digit long. Thank you.
**02012B1530A6E3958A98530031902003876940000000000CDF9844173BE512AFFFFFFE11DBBA1F00079387800E13012E11FC017FFFFFFFFE39C10F40**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true, that one hex digit corresponds to 4 bits.
So you just covert

- 0 => 0000
- ...
- f => 1111

When you do this with the given number it starts with 0000 0010. Like with decimal numbers, leading zeros can be removed or added as you like, so all answers with more or less leading zeros can be correct.
Hex and binary are just other number systems like decimal.

In case of integers, you typically want to remove all leading zeros, lime with decimal numbers.

but when it is a byte or bit array that represents data, you would keep them, because 0 actually represents the value 0.

Ihr calculator that gives you 480 as result probably interprets it as a byte or bit array and therefore keeps the leading zeros.
476 seems to remove leading hex zeros and then keeps eventual the up to 3 leading binary zeros. No idea how you would end up with 478 digits.

However the common outputs should have 480 or 474 digits, depending if all zeros are kept or none. Everything else does not really make sense, eventhoug it is not technically wrong.